# List of tuples to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Here's how I'm currently converting a list of tuples to dictionary in Python:

```
l = [('a',1),('b',2)]
h = {}
[h.update({k:v}) for k,v in l]
> [None, None]
h
> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Is there a better way?  It seems like there should be a one-liner to do this.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Just call [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) on the list of tuples directly

```
>>> my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
>>> dict(my_list)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Derp, I knew there would be a simple way to do it...  Coming from Ruby here, trying to learn the Python way of doing things.  Thanks!

Comment: @chandresh This _does_ work in Python 3, so no update is required.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, Here is my output of the same command you have written above on py 3.5 terminal. Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-313-7bb3559567ff>", line 1, in <module>
    dict(my_list)

TypeError: 'Dictionary' object is not callable

Comment: @chandresh This has nothing to do with Python 3 – it's because you have a variable called `dict`, shadowing the Python built-in of the same name.  You should never do that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Oh. Thanks. It worked. Actually, I got some code from the web and tried to run this. Looks like the author had used `dict` as variable name from where I got the error. Thanks again.

Comment: If have redundant numbers, it doesn't work properly [('0', '1'), ('0', '3'), ('3', '2')]
result : {'0': '3', '3': '2'} instead of {'0':['1', '3'], '3': '2'}

Comment: @Rim It's not clear at all what the desired outcome is in the presence of duplicate keys. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9840828) for one way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 32):

It seems everyone here assumes the list of tuples have one to one mapping between key and values (e.g. it does not have duplicated keys for the dictionary). As this is the first question coming up searching on this topic, I post an answer for a more general case where we have to deal with duplicates:

```
mylist = [(a,1),(a,2),(b,3)]    
result = {}
for i in mylist:  
   result.setdefault(i[0],[]).append(i[1])
print(result)
>>> result = {a:[1,2], b:[3]}
```

Comment: Or just use `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar don't forget to import defaultdict from collections before!

Answer (score 25):

The `dict` constructor accepts input exactly as you have it (key/value tuples).

```
>>> l = [('a',1),('b',2)]
>>> d = dict(l)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> For example, these all return a
>   dictionary equal to {"one": 1, "two":
>   2}:
>
> ```
> dict(one=1, two=2)
> dict({'one': 1, 'two': 2})
> dict(zip(('one', 'two'), (1, 2)))
> dict([['two', 2], ['one', 1]])
> ```

Answer (score 24):

With `dict` comprehension:

```
h = {k:v for k,v in l}
```

Comment: nice because it allows you to do formatting on the key / value before adding it to the dict

Comment: Nice, also because this works for Python 2.  The above answers do not.

Answer (score 2):

Functional decision for @pegah answer:

```py
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 4)]
#mylist = iter([('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 4)])

result = { k : [*map(lambda v: v[1], values)]
    for k, values in groupby(sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])
    }

print(result)
# {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```