# How do I turn a list of tuples into a dictionary while keeping redundant values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm getting a data set that's formatted as a list of key-value pairs. The key is the data source, and the value is the data element. For example:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('a', 7), ('c', 15), ('d', 12)]
```

I want to turn this list into a dictionary. I could use Python's built-in `dict()`, but it throws away redundant values and keeps only the last value associated with a given key. I would like redundant values to go into a list, as follows:

```
{'a': [3, 7],
'b': [5],
'c': [15],
'd': [12]}
```

Is there a simple way to do the above? I think there has to be, but I can't seem to find the right hint via Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dict` subclass `defaultdict` in the `collections` module can be used to automatically initialize a new `list` for each key the first time you access it.

With it, you just need to loop through the input pairs and append each value to the `list` of the corresponding key in order to produce the lists of values you want.

```
import collections    

data = [('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('a', 7), ('c', 15), ('d', 12)]
result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, value in data:
    result[key].append(value)

print result
```

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [3, 7], 'c': [15], 'b': [5], 'd': [12]})
```

```
print result['a']
```

```
[3, 7]
```

```
print result['z']
```

```
[]
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about `defaultdict` until today. Another wrench in my python toolbox!

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `setdefault()` method of dictionaries:

```
d = {}
for key, value in my_list:
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

This can also be done with a `defaultdict`.  Which of the two options is preferable depends on how `d` is used in the rest of the code.  A `defaultdict` will never give you a `KeyError`, so it might hide errors further down in the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
def multidict(lst):
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in lst:
        result[key].append(value)
    return result # or dict(result) if you don't want to keep defaultdict
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('a', 7), ('c', 15), ('d', 12)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l:
    d[k].append(v)
print d
```

See the first example here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Both [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) and [paste](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/util.multidict.html) offer multidict implementations. Pick one, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
 >>> d=[('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('a', 7), ('c', 15), ('d', 12)]
 >>> f={}
 >>> for k,v in d:
 ...     f[k]=f.get(k,[])+[v]
 ... 
 >>> f
 {'a': [3, 7], 'c': [15], 'b': [5], 'd': [12]}
```

Comment: `f.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)` would be more straightforward than `f[k]=f.get(k,[])+[v]`

Comment: agreed, they are almost equivalent though.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: The main advantage of using `setdefault()` is that it does not make the code O(n^2).

Comment: @user999346: No, they are not equivalent.  The `setdefault()` way reuses the list onces it was created, while your approach copies all items to a new list each time an item is appended.

Comment: @user999346:  Addition of list to list creates a new list which is then assigned back to the dictionary.  This will become quite inefficient as the number of values stored in the list grows.