# Convert a list of tuples to python dictionary without losing the order

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to convert a list of tuples to a dictionary but when I do it using the dict() function, the order of the elements is changed:

```
l = [('id', 2), ('osm_id', 3), ('sourceid', 4), ('notes', 5), ('ref', 6), ('rtenme', 7), ('ntlclass', 8), ('fclass', 9), ('numlanes', 10), ('srftpe', 11), ('srfcond', 12), ('isseasonal', 13), ('curntprac', 14), ('gnralspeed', 15), ('rdwidthm', 16), ('status', 17), ('bridge', 18), ('iso3', 19), ('country', 20), ('last_updat', 21)]

 dict_l = dict(l)
 print (dict_l)

{'fclass': 9, 'status': 17, 'isseasonal': 13, 'bridge': 18, 'sourceid': 4, 'country': 20, 'notes': 5, 'rtenme': 7, 'iso3': 19, 'last_updat': 21, 'gnralspeed': 15, 'osm_id': 3, 'srfcond': 12, 'numlanes': 10, 'srftpe': 11, 'rdwidthm': 16, 'ref': 6, 'id': 2, 'ntlclass': 8, 'curntprac': 14}
```

What am I missing here?

I also tried to loop through the list of tuples and build the dict manually as:

```
c = 0
for key, value in display_order_list_sorted:
    display_order_dict_sorted[display_order_list_sorted[c][0]] = display_order_list_sorted[c][1]
    c = c + 1
```

I faced the same issue.

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered. Use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: See here for an explanation: [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

Comment: You may be pleased to learn that in Python 3.6 [dictionaries _are_ ordered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6). This is currently an implementation detail & shouldn't be relied on, however, it may eventually become an actual language feature.

Comment: These are great news. But we are in 2.7 :)

Comment: Python 2 support will cease in 2020, so you better get ready to move to Python 3. :)

Answer (score 9):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
l = [('id', 2), ('osm_id', 3), ('sourceid', 4), ('notes', 5), ('ref', 6), ('rtenme', 7), ('ntlclass', 8), ('fclass', 9), ('numlanes', 10), ('srftpe', 11), ('srfcond', 12), ('isseasonal', 13), ('curntprac', 14), ('gnralspeed', 15), ('rdwidthm', 16), ('status', 17), ('bridge', 18), ('iso3', 19), ('country', 20), ('last_updat', 21)]

dict_l = OrderedDict(l)
print (dict_l)
```

Comment: So then this answer is misleading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522446/list-of-tuples-to-dictionary

Comment: @user1919, how so?

Comment: Cause I do the same thing (converting an ordered by value list of tuples to a dictionary) and I don't get an odered by value dictionary as this answer implies.

Comment: It's not misleading, it's just not clear. Dictionary COULD return an ordered dictionary  the way you like it, but it's just once in a blue moon if you have a lot of entry. It's "random" basically how it's displayed.

Comment: As the first entry in the tuple is used as the key, it would be prudent to make sure that the key is not repeated in the original list. Otherwise, some information would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Python dictionary is not ordered. You need to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).</strike>

Gulzar rightfully pointed out in the comments, Python dictionaries are now guaranteed to maintain insertion order starting from Python 3.7

Comment: If you are going to give the same answer as the comment, maybe give an example?

Comment: Yeah, atm that I posted the answer the comment contained only a link that I didnt opened before posting. The example is in the @Ari Gold's answer.

Comment: Not true starting Python >=3.7