# Append a list of tuples into a existing dictionary

Tags: python

I have an existing dictionary and I want to add a list of tuples into this dictionary.

Existing dictionary structure:

```
myD = {'key1': 123 , 'key2': 456}
```

List of tuples structure:

```
myL = [('fkey1',321),('fkey2',432),('fkey3',543)]
```

Expected dictionary after adding list of tuples

```
myD = {'key1': 123 ,'key2': 456 ,'fkey': 321 ,'fkey2': 432 ,'fkey3': 543}
```

How can I implement this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of tuples to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522446/list-of-tuples-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

```
>>> myD = {'key1': 123 , 'key2': 456}
>>> myL = [('fkey1',321),('fkey2',432),('fkey3',543)]
>>> 
>>> myD.update(myL)
>>> 
>>> myD
{'key2': 456, 'key1': 123, 'fkey1': 321, 'fkey2': 432, 'fkey3': 543}
```

Answer (score 4):

use simple `for loop statment`

```
myD = {'key1': 123 , 'key2': 456}

myL = [('fkey1',321),('fkey2',432),('fkey3',543)]

for k, v in myL:
    myD[k] = v

print(myD)
```

or use  `update`

```
myD.update(myL)                                                                                                                                                                                              

print(myD)
```

**Output**

```
{'key1': 123, 'key2': 456, 'fkey1': 321, 'fkey2': 432, 'fkey3': 543}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `dict.update`

**Ex:**

```
myD = {'key1': 123 , 'key2': 456}
myL = [('fkey1',321),('fkey2',432),('fkey3',543)]
myD.update(myL)
print(myD)
```

**Output:**

```
{'key2': 456, 'key1': 123, 'fkey1': 321, 'fkey2': 432, 'fkey3': 543}
```

Comment: No need to convert `myL` to a dict: `myD.update(myL)` will work just fine.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary unpacking:

```
>>> >>> myD = {'key1': 123 , 'key2': 456}
>>> myL = [('fkey1',321),('fkey2',432),('fkey3',543)]
>>> {**myD, **dict(myL)}
{'key1': 123, 'key2': 456, 'fkey1': 321, 'fkey2': 432, 'fkey3': 543}
```