# Convert a list of tuples to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples with three elements:

```
A = [[(72, 1, 2), (96, 1, 4)], 
     [(72, 2, 1), (80, 2, 4)], 
     [], 
     [(96, 4, 1), (80, 4, 2), (70, 4, 5)],
     [(70, 5, 4)],
     ]
```

I need to convert it to a dictionary in this format (note that the second element in the tuple will be the key):

```
A_dict = { 1: {2:72, 4:96},
           2: {1:72, 4:80},
           3: {},
           4: {1:96, 2:80, 5:70},
           5: {4:70},
         }
```

Is there a way to convert A to A_dict?

I tried this:

```
A_dict = {b:{a:c} for a,b,c in A}
```

but I got an error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please show your attempts from your research and explain what went wrong.

Comment: @roganjosh I added my unsuccessful solution at the end.

Comment: Possible  duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522446/list-of-tuples-to-dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of tuples to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522446/list-of-tuples-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
A_dict = {k+1: {t[2]: t[0] for t in l} for k, l in enumerate(A)}

>>> A_dict
{
 1: {2: 72, 4: 96}, 
 2: {1: 72, 4: 80}, 
 3: {}, 
 4: {1: 96, 2: 80, 5: 70}, 
 5: {4: 70}
}
```

Comment: While this works on the OP's stated input, I'm not sure we can take for granted that the second element of each tuple is always one greater than its index in A. In other words, `k+1` seems like a brittle solution for determining the key of `A_dict`.

Comment: @Kevin Doesn't `k` come from `enumerate` though?

Answer (score 2):

By iterating on the indices of the list, according to its length. And for each value building its own dictionary:

```
A_dict = {i + 1 : {v[2] : v[0] for v in A[i]} for i in range(len(A))}
```

will output:

```
{1: {2: 72, 4: 96},
 2: {1: 72, 4: 80},
 3: {},
 4: {1: 96, 2: 80, 5: 70},
 5: {4: 70}}
```

Actually your desired code is:

```
A_dict = {A[i][0][1] : {v[2] : v[0] for v in A[i]} for i in range(len(A)) if len(A[i]) > 0}
```

But that will 'skip' the third line, as there is no list, thus not able to determinate the actual key, according to your specification.

Comment: While this works on the OP's stated input, I'm not sure we can take for granted that the second element of each tuple is always one greater than its index in A. In other words, `i+1` seems like a brittle solution for determining the key of `A_dict`.

Comment: You are correct, but that is not consistent with his expected output, I will, however, fix this.